# define column Name in datatable

Tags: vb.net

The Column Name is (Net Due) I am using "_" instead of the space but doesn't work.

```
Dim newview As New DataView(Dt_Result)
        newview.RowFilter = $"Net_Due <> '0'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use square brakets around the column name.

```vbnet
Dim newview As New DataView(Dt_Result)
newview.RowFilter = $"[Net Due] <> '0'"
```

Comment: work well ,Thanks .